# How to exclude from a "Match Group" in SSHD?

Tags: openssh, sshd

There is a Match group in the SSHD config:

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
    Match Group FOOGROUP
    ForceCommand /bin/customshell
...
```

There are many users on the machine that are in the "FOOGROUP".

**My question:** How can I exclude a given user that is in the "FOOGROUP" from the "Match Group"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Match` operator can take multiple arguments, allowing very flexible rules. In this case, you could do something like this to achieve what you want.

```
Match Group FOOGROUP User !username
  ForceCommand /bin/customshell
```

The `!` negates the argument passed to the `User` criterion, so even if the user `username` is in the group `FOOGROUP`, the `Match` will not be successful, and `username` will not be given the custom shell upon logging in.

Comment: And are you 100% sure, that this only excludes the "!username"? And other users that could be in the FOOGROUP will be untouched?

Comment: Yes. I tested it before posting, and it works as I describe.

Comment: It seems the `*,!username` is a more clean approach. Yet another case your solution fail is mixing this kind of `Match` with `ChrootDirectory` (tested on both openssh 5.3p1 and 7.4p1).

Answer (score 8):

You need to use multiple clauses in your config file entry but in a very specific way.  There is a bug in some setups that cause the generally recommended, and simplest, syntax ( "Match Group FOOGROUP User !username" ) to either cause everyone else in the group to fail to Match or lets them escape their chroot jail.

On Debian Jessie using OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2d I get the result that everyone else in the group can no longer connect.  [Others](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/507600-Exclude-a-single-group-user-from-chroot-jail) report jail breaks.  In both cases a syntax of

```
Match Group FOOGROUP User *,!username
```

seems to work without side-effects.  Some sort of bug in the parser no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

with below option i can jail the sftp user within specified directory and also specified user able to login thru ssh.

```
Match Group groupname User *,!username
```

Thanks.