# Can not succeed in excluding user in match directive in SSHD config

Tags: ssh, configuration, sshd

I’m having a problem with my sshd config. I want to limit all users of the group *www-user* to sftp use. All of them but the user *yorunokoe*.

I saw that related question : [How to exclude from a "Match Group" in SSHD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137422/how-to-exclude-from-a-match-group-in-sshd) and my config end like this :

```
Match Group www-user User !yorunokoe
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  PermitTunnel no
  X11Forwarding no
```

But that doesn’t work. I tested different variations and it seems that everytime I use the exclamation mark, the whole directive returns as false and no subsequent config is applied. With the above config, all users still have SSH access, they’re not chrooted and they’re not limited to sftp.

I’m running with OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1k

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try `User *,!yorunokoe`. See [this question](http://serverfault.com/a/44868/154554) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: It works ! I was missing the wildcard part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28235/n-st, the correct config is :

```
Match Group www-user User *,!yorunokoe
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  PermitTunnel no
  X11Forwarding no
```

That limit all users in *www-user* except user *yorunokoe* to sftp.

Comment: Hi Jérôme, I upvoted your question yesterday as a good one.
I'd suggest that you accept your answer to let other users know that your issue is now resolved. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Otherwise, the question continues to be listed as an *unanswered* question.
Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!